# Does adding sort keys to Redshift table speed up delete statements?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, psycopg2, sql-delete

I have a very large table in Redshift with ~36M rows that uses composite keys. I am trying to perform massive delete + copying (S3 copy command) operations every half minute. We have an ETL pipeline that tries to update our data warehouse tables near real-time. Currently I am using psycopg2's `executemany` method to delete rows, this method basically batches up my delete queries and performs many small

```
delete from table where col1=val1 and col2=val2 ...
```

in a for loop (I am probably over-simplifying the implementation). If I altered my table to make the composite keys into sortkeys, would this speed up my deletes?

Comment: What do you mean by "composite keys"? Are you referring to the SORTKEYs?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I know Redshift doesn't enforce primary/composite key constraints but I am doing that on my side. By "composite keys" I mean multiple columns that can be used to uniquely identify a single record in my table. My idea was hoping to make these columns into sort keys, I guess the idea does not make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 2):

Using `DELETE` on Redshift tables isn't great. It simply marks rows as deleted, but leaves the data in place until a future `VACUUM`.

It is sometimes better to perform a `CREATE TABLE AS` to extract all rows *except* the rows that you want to delete. This creates a new table, stored optimally, without any deleted rows.

It sounds like you might be trying to implement UPSERT functionality. If so, see: [Use a Staging Table to Perform a Merge (Upsert) - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html)

Performing operations on a 36M row table every half minute might not be well-suited for doing within Redshift. It is optimized for loading from S3 and for querying, not running delete/insert statements.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help John, I eventually stumbled upon AWS's advice of using ```delete from table using...``` query

Comment: That's interesting! Can you provide a link?

Comment: yeah sure, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DELETE.html. Scroll down to the `USING` keyword section